# How to select all the tables together in a database in MYSQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

For example, there are 11 tables in my database. To see the details of the tables, I have to do **select * from table_name** 11 times and pin the respective tabs. Is there any way that I could write a single query to return all the data from all the tables in the database.

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: Version: 8.0.19

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I don't think you can return all data from each table individually in one Single Query without merging all the tables together or performing some sort of join.

Comment: you can't do *anything* with more than one table without some sort of join :)

Answer (score 0):

You can dump all the tables out like so (example only includes two tables, foo and bar):

```
with recursive rownum (rownum) as (
    select 1
    union all
    select rownum+1 from rownum
    where rownum < greatest(
        (select count(*) from foo),
        (select count(*) from bar)
    )
)
select foo_rows.*, bar_rows.*
from rownum
left join (
    select row_number() over () foo_row, foo.* from foo
) foo_rows on foo_row=rownum
left join(
    select row_number() over () bar_row, bar.* from bar
) bar_rows on bar_row=rownum;
```

Comment: @ArkoDas is this what you were looking for?